# Django - Filter when Case is false

Tags: python, django

I have a model `Article`. That should be filtered. Here's the condition:

**If** the request is NOT an author, all articles with `pub_date` lte `now` will be visible.

**If** the request is an author, all articles with `pub_date` lte `now` will be visible PLUS articles from the authors (regardless of `pub_date`).

In simple language: Everyone should only see the articles, which hasn't been published, but authors can also see their articles.

---

I thought I could annotate the articles and then somehow filter on them, but I have no idea how to continue or how to do it. `authors` is a m2m field.

```
articles = articles.annotate(
                can_see=Case(
                    When(authors__id__in=[request.user.id], then=Value(True)),
                    default=False,
                    output_field=BooleanField()
                )
            )
```

Comment: Please show your models so you can get a proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can deduce of your code you can use a simple `OR` in your filter. Essentially you would do something like:

```py
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import Q

now = timezone.now()
to_show = articles.filter(Q(authors__id=request.user.id) | Q(pub_date__lte=now))
```

This performs a logical or between the tow criteria enclosed in the `Q()` objects. What this query is saying is "bring every article that either has an author whose id matches the user id in the request or whose publication date is less than or equal to the current date"

Please take a look at [the documentation on querying the databse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Comment: Oh my god, I literally have no idea why I'm so dumb sometimes. That should definitely work. Thank you!